# How to restart a stalled iOS restore?

Tags: restore, ios

I updated my iPhone 5s to iOS 7 using restore install. This cleared the iPhone and then started a restore from iCloud. However, sometime during the restore stalled and did not complete. (In the iCloud settings panel it says "You cannot delete you iCloud account because your phone is being restored.) However, when I leave my phone plugged in overnight the restore process doesn't continue. Is there any way to restart the restore process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact steps, but after backing up and updating the OS to 7.0.1 via iTunes, the warnings went away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you visited the [iCloud Backup Restore Troubleshoot Site](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4036) provided by Apple? If so, which steps did you already tried?

[This](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12521?viewlocale=en_US) may also help you. The site is describing how to restore your iOS Device from an iCloud Backup.

Comment: I looked through those documents before and once again. They don't describe how to restart an in-process restore.